# Can I have launchctl output stdout/stderr from my application to the system-wide Unified Logging mechanism?

Tags: launchd, logs

I have set up a custom `.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` to run a process ([offlineimap](http://www.offlineimap.org/)) on a periodic basis. I've specified both the `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys to point to files in my home directory, which works. However, this doesn't really provide a complete logging solution from what I can see. The logs are not rotated, there are no timestamps (addressed by [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52780/filter-launchctl-standard-err-out-to-add-timestamp-to-log-messages), although there was no clear answer), and the log is not integrated into any other logging on the system. I think I would prefer it if the logs went to [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging).

I'm used to systemd logging on Linux, which is a similar mechanism, and it would be great if there was a similar way I could redirect that output into the system-wide log, viewable with the `log` command. Is there any way to do that with a custom LaunchAgent?

I should add that I'm using MacOS 10.14.5.

Comment: If you want to get proper logging of your processes, you need to move your logs to `/etc/asl` and then configure them in `/etc/asl.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. Doing a bit more reading, it seems that unified logging supersedes ASL (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging). However, what's not clear is how I can use launchd to redirect the stdout from my application to either of those!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`blowhole`](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/12/want-to-write-a-message-to-the-unified-log-blowhole-v9-will-do-that-for-you/).

`blowhole` is a command-line tool that takes a string as an argument and sends it to the **unified logging system**. It is supported from Sierra (10.12) up to Catalina (10.15).

### How to use it

(Tested on macOS Catalina 10.15.5)

Modify the [`ProgramArguments` array](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-104142-BCICCCFI) in your `.plist` file like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>COMMAND OPTIONS 2> >(while read; do /path/to/blowhole -e "$REPLY"; done) | while read; do /path/to/blowhole -d "$REPLY"; done</string>
```

where `COMMAND OPTIONS` is the command you want to execute, followed by any desired options.

Here, I make use of `bash`'s support for [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (`2>`), [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (`>()`) and [pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines) (`|`) to:

- sort out the command's standard error and standard output
- process them separately inside two `while` loops. The first `while` loop runs `blowhole -e` to log standard error with an "Error" level:

  > `<timestamp> Error <info> blowhole: [co.eclecticlight.blowhole:general] Blowhole: STANDARD ERROR MESSAGES`

  and the second one runs `blowhole -d` to log standard output with a "Default" level:

  > `<timestamp> Default <info> blowhole: [co.eclecticlight.blowhole:general] Blowhole: STANDARD OUTPUT MESSAGES`

  (Since `blowhole` can't read from standard input, we need [`while`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs) loops to feed it a line of input at a time.)

The `blowhole: [co.eclecticlight.blowhole:general] Blowhole:` string is not configurable, but you can add a prefix of your choice to the logged messages. For example, since you mention `offlineimap` in your question:

> `/path/to/blowhole -d "offlineimap stdout: $REPLY";`

and:

> `/path/to/blowhole -e "offlineimap stderr: $REPLY";`

You can read log entries with `sudo log show | grep blowhole:general` or `sudo log show | grep offlineimap`, if you added the customized prefix. To read log entries as they are generated, in a manner similar to `tail -f`, use `show stream` instead.

**Alternatively**, you can wrap the command you want to execute in a shell script so that `blowhole` logs the command's standard output and error in a way similar to above. This is convenient if you want to run some code prior to executing the actual command:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Add the code you want to execute prior to the actual command here
COMMAND ARGUMENTS \
> >(
while read; do 
    /path/to/blowhole -d "$REPLY"; 
done) \
2> >(
while read; do 
    /path/to/blowhole -e "$REPLY"; 
done)
```

You can then configure the `ProgramArguments` array of your `.plist` file to run the script instead of your command:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>/path/to/script.sh</string>
</array>
```

### Where to get it from

You can download `blowhole` from [its project page](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/06/12/want-to-write-a-message-to-the-unified-log-blowhole-v9-will-do-that-for-you/) or directly from [here](https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2019/06/blowhole9.zip). The program is provided as a signed, hardened and notarized executable (as required by Catalina) and as an Installer package.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great and comprehensive answer; I'll try it out. It's a shame that this involves writing a wrapper shell-script for each agent, but it looks like it should work. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I'm glad you found my answer useful. I agree with you about the wrapper shell script, I found a way to get rid of it and expanded my question accordingly, you may want to give it try. If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you marked it as accepted. Thank you.